# Multiple custom kernels vs linux-libc-dev

Tags: kernel, compiling, debian

**The goal:** compile and install a new kernel (compiled from a different source) `alongside` the existing (stock) one.

I have been out of touch with kernel building for the last few years. In the good old days, I would compile a new kernel package, install it, and it would show up *alongside* my existing kernels when booting.

I did essentially the same, but I ended up with more packages that I used to:

```
make deb-pkg

linux-headers....deb
linux-image....deb
linux-firmware-image....deb
linux-libc-dev....deb  // <---
```

Upon checking the contents of these packages, most of them have a versioned subdir. `linux-libc-dev....deb`, however, just spits its content into `/usr`, without an special path prefix. Meaning it will overwrite whatever the stock package / the custom build before it has put in there...

**The question:** how can I use multiple kernels on th same system?

Is it somehow safe to install a dozen versions of `linux-libc-dev....deb` over-and-over?

Shall I just forgo installing, and pretend this is not there, and the stock version `linux-libc-dev....deb` will do a perfect job supporting another kernel?

---

Not sure, if its relevant, I am building a newer kernel than I have as stock, going from `4.9.144` to `4.9.160`, and `4.20.11`. (I am trying to test out an error with different kernels.)

---

I DID see a lot of posts on "what is linux-libc-dev", none of which answered my question.

Comment: You need image and headers.

Comment: Could you expand on it, in that case, in which situation would the linux-libc-dev....deb needed?